# LinearLayout selector doesn't cover the whole View's children

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

The following is my XML code, I need to make a selector for the LinearLayout, but when I tap on the child TextView it doesn't show the selector backgroud as tapping other areas of the LinearLayout!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <ImageView android:paddingLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/chart"/>

    <TextView android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/tv_title" />

    <ImageView android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_48dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_bookmark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextView android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

I think the reason for the error is because `descendantFocusability` is only for focusing state. It does not affect touch events. Since the `TextView` is still clickable it can still consume the touch event, and thus keep the parent from consuming the click.

Edit:

Try setting `android:descendantFocusability` to `beforeDescendants` instead of `blocksDescendants`.

**Edit 2**:

Changing the parent to `android:addStatesFromChildren="true"` and removing the `clickable` and `focusable` from the child `TextView` seemed to do the trick. This works because according to the `ViewGroup` android docs:

> addStatesFromChildren: Sets whether this ViewGroup's drawable states also include its children's drawable states.

So when the child will set its state it also sets its parents state.

Comment: Well then @AkramQalalwa what exactly is it that you are trying to do? Is the whole `LinearLayout` clickable? Or just the `TextView`. Also, what do you mean by it doesn't work? What happens if it doesnt work? Is the `TextView` still being clicked? Or is the focus just not happening on the parent?

Comment: The selection background appears when I tap on any area inside the LinearLayout but not on the TextView .. when I tap on it nothing happens, but the functionality of tapping is working means it moves me to another activity no matter where I tap ... so the problem is in the selector only when tapping on the TextView!

Comment: Ok. Try adding this on the parent `android:addStatesFromChildren="true"`, but removing the `clickable` and `focusable` bits from the `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` to `false` in your `TextView`.

Comment: Can you try it after removing `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` from the `LinearLayout`?